# Python - How do I call class method from another newly modified python file

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods

I'm new in python programming and would like to seek help in calling a method from another newly modified python file.

I currently have 3 python files: main.py, addBody.py, and originalBody.py.

The addBody will add one segment of the body to originalBody.py in each iteration. This is done by read and write function.

For example,

in the first iteration (initiated from main.py), originalBody.py will look like:

```
class BODY:
    def __init__(self):
        object1 = send_cylinder(length = 1.0, radius = 0.1)
        bodySegment = {}
        bodySegment[0] = 1  #one body
```

in second iteration, originalBody.py will automatically look like:

```
class BODY:
    def __init__(self):
        object1 = send_cylinder(length = 1.0, radius = 0.1)
        object2 = send_cylinder(length = 1.0, radius = 0.1)
        bodySegment = {}
        bodySegment[0] = 1  #one body
        bodySegment[1] = 2  #two body
```

When I'm trying to call the class from main.py,

main.py

```
from originalBody import BODY

for i in range (0,10):

    fileToRead = open('addBody.py')
    fileToAppend = open('originalBody.py', 'a')
    ...(add body from addBody.py to originalBody.py)...
    fileToAppend.close()
    fileToRead.close()

    parent = BODY()
    print(parent.bodySegment)
```

in the first iteration it runs smoothly:

```
{0: 1}
```

In the second iteration, after adding the body segment to originalBody.py, supposedly the result is expected to print out:

```
{0: 1, 1: 2}
```

However, it prints out the result from the first iteration:

```
{0: 1}
```

I suspect that my code calls the function from the original version of originalBody.py that has not modified yet. Do I need to add in some code in my main to get the class method from the modified version of originalBody? Or do I need to add in time delay to call the method right after the modification of originalBody?

Comment: Seems you may want to reload the file? Did you look into imp---particularly load_source?

Comment: So you modify your already loaded code at runtime? Why?

Comment: @mattsap should be considered as that since I want to directly get the modified file. I haven't look into that yet, will try to search for it

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I wanna let the system to modify the code by itself to automatically add body segment in each iteration

Comment: It is unclear why that needs modifying the original class and especially the *source code*. Subclassing would allow representing distinct classes with different capabilities, and `eval` would allow reusability. Currently, every time you run the program more body parts are added...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I tried subclassing before for my code (got a lot more on adding the body which did not post here). But, due to the limitation of the simulation that I'm trying to run, it does not work when running graphical display as it only showed last added body, others still there but went invisible. I do admit it's a con in this aspect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reload a module when it has already been imported by using the **reload** builtin function.

I edited your code using `import originalBody` because I am not sure how the reload function works with the `from x import y` syntax.

Code below:

```
from importlib import reload
import originalBody

for i in range (0,10):
    reload(originalBody)

    fileToRead = open('addBody.py')
    fileToAppend = open('originalBody.py', 'a')
    ...(add body from addBody.py to originalBody.py)...
    fileToAppend.close()
    fileToRead.close()

    parent = originalBody.BODY()
    print(parent.bodySegment)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps to solve my issue. Just that reload() is for python 2. In my case for python 3.3, 'import imp    imp.reload()' will do the trick

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified the version. Anyway, reload exists since python 3.4 onwards!